# How to switch Glassfish from outputing in JSON to XML

Tags: xml, json, glassfish

The person that set up our glassfish server is out of contact. We have it so that it will output in both json and xml formats. Currently it is outputting in json but I need xml. How do I change it to xml?

Comment: If this is REST server have you tried changing HTTP Accept header value to `application/xml`

Comment: where do I do that? Currently each of the methods has a header:

@Consumes({"application/xml", "application/json"})

but not sure where in the configuration to specify which to use.

Comment: In the client that is calling the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the client header concern I mentioned ended up being the solution, I will just go ahead and enter the solution here for anyone else who may encounter it.

In this case, the client calling the server needs to specify the HTTP Accept header to send a value of `application/xml`. Many RESTful server implementations utilize this header to determine how to format the response.

Comment: I believe the problem with mine was that I had no accept header specified. So it defaulted to JSON on one version and XML on another.

Comment: and make sure to use the 'Accept' header not 'Content-type'... *sigh*

Comment: @galactikuh Yes 'Content-type' specifies the format of the request while 'Accept' specifies the expected format of the response.

Comment: Oddly, using 'Content-type' worked fine when I was running on localhost, but when I deployed to the real server it went back to JSON.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using some REST framework. Some of your server application classes may look like this:

```
@GET
@Path("/somepath")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public SomeClass getSomething();
```

The [@Produces annotation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/gipxf/index.html) declares which media type can be delivered to the clients.

You'll have to change it to this:

```
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.TEXT_XML})
```

or this

```
@Produces({"application/json", "application/xml"}))
```

This should work if the class `SomeClass` is annotated as [@XmlRootElement](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlRootElement.html). If the method is returning some "standard" class like String you can do it like this:

```
  // This method is called if XML is requested
  @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
  public String getXML() {
    return "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>" + "<hello> Hello" + "</hello>";
  }

  // This method is called if JSON is requested
  @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  public String getJSON() {
    return "{ 'hello': 'Hello' }";
  }
```

Comment: Thanks. Turns out the problem was on the client side. I think because I hadn't specified request header type it defaulted to JSON.